# Cannot load squeezeNet 1.0 or 1.1 by opencv3.2

Tags: c++, opencv

I pull the source codes from opencv and opencv_contrib today(2017/06/28), trying to load the squeezeNet models list at here as following example

```
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
/* Find best class for the blob (i. e. class with maximal probability) */
static void getMaxClass(const Mat &probBlob, int *classId, double *classProb)
{
    Mat probMat = probBlob.reshape(1, 1); //reshape the blob to 1x1000 matrix
    Point classNumber;
    minMaxLoc(probMat, NULL, classProb, NULL, &classNumber);
    *classId = classNumber.x;
}
static std::vector<String> readClassNames(const char *filename = "synset_words.txt")
{
    std::vector<String> classNames;
    std::ifstream fp(filename);
    if (!fp.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "File with classes labels not found: " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    std::string name;
    while (!fp.eof())
    {
        std::getline(fp, name);
        if (name.length())
            classNames.push_back( name.substr(name.find(' ')+1) );
    }
    fp.close();
    return classNames;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::dnn::initModule();  //Required if OpenCV is built as static libs
    String modelTxt = "train_val.prototxt";
    String modelBin = "squeezenet_v1.1.caffemodel";
    String imageFile = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "space_shuttle.jpg";
    Net net = dnn::readNetFromCaffe(modelTxt, modelBin);
    if (net.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't load network by using the following files: " << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "prototxt:   " << modelTxt << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "caffemodel: " << modelBin << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel can be downloaded here:" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    Mat img = imread(imageFile);
    if (img.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't read image from the file: " << imageFile << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    //GoogLeNet accepts only 224x224 RGB-images
    Mat inputBlob = blobFromImage(img, 1, Size(224, 224),
                                  Scalar(104, 117, 123));   //Convert Mat to batch of images
    net.setInput(inputBlob, "data");        //set the network input
    Mat prob = net.forward("prob");                          //compute output
    int classId;
    double classProb;
    getMaxClass(prob, &classId, &classProb);//find the best class
    std::vector<String> classNames = readClassNames();
    std::cout << "Best class: #" << classId << " '" << classNames.at(classId) << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Probability: " << classProb * 100 << "%" << std::endl;
    return 0;
} //main
```

But it give me following error(works well with google net)

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Duplicate blobs produced by multiple
>   sources) in addOutput, file
>   /home/ramsus/Qt/3rdLibs/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_importer.cpp,
>   line 327
>   /home/ramsus/Qt/3rdLibs/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_importer.cpp:327:
>   error: (-5) Duplicate blobs produced by multiple sources in function
>   addOutput

How could I import squeezeNet_v1.1 by opencv?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mat prob = net.forward("prob"); 
change to 
Mat prob = net.forward("softmax");